# How to remove all files from folders?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm getting a list of folders with command

```
locate my_folder
```

How i can empty/delete all files from those folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove everything inside the folders and the folders themselves, pipe this:

```
locate my_folder | xargs rm -rf
```

> **Warning:** No confirmation prompt or progress indication; irreversible data loss

<sup><sub>[Explanation of `xargs rm -rf`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=xargs+rm+-rf)</sub></sup>

---

If you want to remove everything inside the folders but keep the folders themselves, pipe this:

```
locate my_folder | xargs -I{} find "{}" -mindepth 1 -delete
```

> **Warning:** No confirmation prompt or progress indication; irreversible data loss

<sup><sub>[Explanation of `xargs -I{} find "{}" -mindepth 1 -delete`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=xargs+-I%7B%7D+find+%22%7B%7D%22+-mindepth+1+-delete)</sub></sup>